# SessionManager.endCurrentSession(false) stops casting

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast-sdk

I am using SessionManager to manage a Cast session to a Chromecast device. In my Activity `onPause()` I have the following code:

```
val sessionManager = castContext.sessionManager
sessionManager.removeSessionManagerListener(castSessionManagerListener, CastSession::class.java)
sessionManager.endCurrentSession(false)
```

I found out that the receiver applications stops. I checked the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/SessionManager#public-void-endcurrentsession-boolean-stopcasting) and it says:

```
public void endCurrentSession (boolean stopCasting)

Ends the current session.
stopCasting     Should the receiver application be stopped when ending the current Session.
```

Even though I use `false` it still stops the receiver application. Why? I want the receiver application to keep streaming even if my application is in background or closed completely. For example, the YouTube app works that way.

Comment: I found my own solution to avoid this. But it requires to NOT use mediaRouter.select(route_you_need). Instead I use castContext.startSession(intent). If you want, I can write here more.